# Помогите с кодом пожалуйста

Tags: c

Программа вводит несколько строк текста и символ для поиска. Используя функцию `strchr`, программа определяет, сколько раз этот символ встречается в строках

```
int main()
{
    int k = 0;
    char str[100];
    char* pch;
    printf("please input 1 line:");
    scanf("%s", str);
    int ch;
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    pch = strchr(str, ch);
    puts(str);
    if (pch == NULL)
        printf("symbol not found\n");
    else
    {
        printf("sumbol %c on place %d\n", ch, pch - str + 1);
        k++;
    }
    printf("k:%d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проблема-то в чём?

Comment: Из правил, так сказать... Правда же, вы их читали? *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).*

Comment: Он не корректно работает

Comment: Гениально. Вы бы хоть написали, как он должен работать корректно... Где - желаемое поведение? Где - конкретная проблема?.. Вы написали, что программа делает ("программа определяет, сколько раз этот символ встречается в строках") - так в чем проблема?.. Откуда мне знать - вы читаете число (`scanf("%d", &ch);`) - может. это ошибка, а может, так и надо - вы вводите код символа. Вот простейший пример недопонимания, что надо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int k = 0;
    char str[100];
    char* pch;
    printf("please input 1 line:");
    fgets(str,100,stdin);
    char ch;
    printf("please input char:");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    for(pch = strchr(str, ch); pch; pch = strchr(pch+1, ch))
    {
        ++k;
    }
    printf("symbol %c found %d times\n", ch, k);
}
```

Но проще без `strchr` - просто пройти по символам:

```
for(pch = str; *pch; pch++)
{
    if (*pch == ch) ++k;
}
```

Comment: С одной стороны, пройтись по символам в самом деле проще (и для коротких строк эффективней), с другой стороны, [strchr](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strchrnul.c) может работать в несколько раз быстрее

Comment: @avp Вы думаете, он реализован не последовательным поиском?...

Comment: Последовательным, но читается и проверяется целиком слово (4 или 8 байт) за раз. А вы код-то посмотрите...